# Warning about app icons when submitting app to Apple store

Tags: ios, app-store

Yesterday, I submitted my app to Apple Store successfully, however, I got a warning:

"Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format."

Actually, I do have this kind of icons in my Resources folder, and I added icon names to plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
            <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                    <array/>
                    <key>Item 0</key>
                    <string>Icon-76.png</string>
                    <key>Item 1</key>
                    <string>Icon-120.png</string>
                    <key>Item 2</key>
                    <string>Icon-152.png</string>
                    <key>Item 3</key>
                    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
                    <key>Item 4</key>
                    <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
                    <key>Item 5</key>
                    <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
                    <key>Item 6</key>
                    <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
                    <key>Item 7</key>
                    <string>Icon.png</string>
                    <key>Item 8</key>
                    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
                    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                    <true/>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
```

Could you tell me what the problem here is?

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged as android?

Comment: sorry, someone has edited tags, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Xcode 5:

Your "Icon-120.png" should be named "Icon-60@2x.png".

"Icon-152.png" should be "Icon-76@2x.png".

In the plist file you leave off the "@2x" part and also the ".png". "Icon-60" and "Icon-60@2x" are both covered by one entry: "Icon-60"

iOS figures out which icon to use based on what kind of display it's running on.